# Securing AbpServiceProxies/GetAll

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, security, aspnetboilerplate, abp

## Problem description

All the routes (URL(s)) for the API (including parameters to use) are accessible to unauthenticated users by calling this API `AbpServiceProxies/GetAll` which doesn't require any token and is not protected.
This opens the application for easy attacks.
Can you please tell me how to secure this API without affecting the normal functionality of the framework.

- Abp package version: 7.4 (last version at the time of writing this issue).
- Base framework: .Net Core.
- Steps needed to reproduce the problem: Just call the API like https://ServerIP/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll

I expect to find a way to secure this API or if it was not possible, at least list only public APIs which has no [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: You can override the GetAll Method on each appService and add the [AbpAuthorize] tag

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help!